# Apache Server: HTTP/2 issues

Tags: linux, debian, apache-httpd, curl

I've just set up a small Apache VM and enabled the HTTP/2 module as described in the documentation ([HTTP/2 guide](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html)). To test it out, the recommendation is to use the non-browser client `curl`. However, I'm noticing some strange issues.

When `curl` is told to use HTTP2 (`curl --http2`), Apache writes 2 lines in the `access.log` instead of the usual single line. Moreover, the date of the 1st line is completely wrong (sometimes even empty) and the protocol of 2nd line is HTTP/1.1 instead of the expected HTTP/2:

```
192.168.122.1 - - [31/Dec/1969:21:00:00 -0300] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 10922 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
192.168.122.1 - - [19/Mar/2023:04:55:34 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 101 10967 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
```

Here's a couple more examples of such issues in `access.log`:

```
192.168.122.1 - -  "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 10922 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
192.168.122.1 - - [19/Mar/2023:06:26:31 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 101 10967 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
192.168.122.1 - -  "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 10922 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
192.168.122.1 - - [19/Mar/2023:06:26:36 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 101 10967 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
192.168.122.1 - - [00/Jan/1900:00:00:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 10922 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
192.168.122.1 - - [19/Mar/2023:06:26:39 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 101 10967 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
192.168.122.1 - - [00/Jan/1900:00:00:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 10922 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
192.168.122.1 - - [19/Mar/2023:06:26:48 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 101 10950 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
```

This issue doesn't happen when `curl` is switched back to HTTP/1.0 or HTTP/1.1.

Any idea?

---

## Debug Info

### VM Setup

- **Virtualization:** `libvirt` managing KVM
- **Operating System:** Debian 11 (only CLI, no DE)
- **Tasksel:**

  ```
    [X] web server
    [X] SSH server
  ```

  Note: everything else unchecked.
- **Apache:** module `http2` enabled in its default configuration

  ```
    root@debian:~# apachectl -M
    AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
    Loaded Modules:
     [...]
     http2_module (shared)
  ```

  Note: `http2` module doesn't work with `prefork` module enabled. However, by default `prefork` module is disabled.

### HTTP 1.0 via curl

```
root@debian:~# curl -v -s --http1.0 http://192.168.122.190/ > /dev/null

*   Trying 192.168.122.190:80...
* Connected to 192.168.122.190 (192.168.122.190) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.0
> Host: 192.168.122.190
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 19 Mar 2023 07:44:03 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian)
< Upgrade: h2,h2c
< Connection: Upgrade, close
< Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Mar 2023 08:12:30 GMT
< ETag: "29cd-5f7142383c2f1"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 10701
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
{ [10701 bytes data]
* Closing connection 0


root@debian:~# tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
[...]
192.168.122.1 - - [19/Mar/2023:04:44:03 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 11001 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
```

### HTTP 1.1 via curl

```
root@debian:~# curl -v -s --http1.1 http://192.168.122.190/ > /dev/null

*   Trying 192.168.122.190:80...
* Connected to 192.168.122.190 (192.168.122.190) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.122.190
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Sun, 19 Mar 2023 07:47:42 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian)
< Upgrade: h2,h2c
< Connection: Upgrade
< Last-Modified: Fri, 17 Mar 2023 08:12:30 GMT
< ETag: "29cd-5f7142383c2f1"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 10701
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
{ [6947 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.122.190 left intact


root@debian:~# tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
[...]
192.168.122.1 - - [19/Mar/2023:04:47:42 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10994 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
```

### HTTP 2.0 via curl

```
root@debian:~# curl -v -s --http2 http://192.168.122.190/ > /dev/null

*   Trying 192.168.122.190:80...
* Connected to 192.168.122.190 (192.168.122.190) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.122.190
> User-Agent: curl/7.74.0
> Accept: */*
> Connection: Upgrade, HTTP2-Settings
> Upgrade: h2c
> HTTP2-Settings: AAMAAABkAAQCAAAAAAIAAAAA
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
< Upgrade: h2c
< Connection: Upgrade
* Received 101
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< last-modified: Fri, 17 Mar 2023 08:12:30 GMT
< etag: W/"29cd-5f7142383c2f1"
< accept-ranges: bytes
< content-length: 10701
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< content-type: text/html
< date: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< server: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian)
< 
{ [7099 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.122.190 left intact


root@debian:~# tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
[...]
192.168.122.1 - - [31/Dec/1969:21:00:00 -0300] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 10922 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
192.168.122.1 - - [19/Mar/2023:04:55:34 -0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 101 10967 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
```

### HTTP 2.0 (non-TLS) via curl

```
root@debian:~# curl -v -s --http2-prior-knowledge http://192.168.122.190/ > /dev/null

*   Trying 192.168.122.190:80...
* Connected to 192.168.122.190 (192.168.122.190) port 80 (#0)
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x561926605ce0)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: 192.168.122.190
> user-agent: curl/7.74.0
> accept: */*
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
< HTTP/2 200 
< last-modified: Fri, 17 Mar 2023 08:12:30 GMT
< etag: "29cd-5f7142383c2f1"
< accept-ranges: bytes
< content-length: 10701
< vary: Accept-Encoding
< content-type: text/html
< date: Sun, 19 Mar 2023 07:59:47 GMT
< server: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian)
< 
{ [10701 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.122.190 left intact


root@debian:~# tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log
[...]
192.168.122.1 - - [19/Mar/2023:04:59:47 -0300] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 200 10920 "-" "curl/7.74.0"
```

### Checking `curl` features:

```
root@debian:~# curl -V
curl 7.74.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.74.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1n zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 libidn2/2.3.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.3.0) libssh2/1.9.0 nghttp2/1.43.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2020-12-09
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Note: Therefore, this `curl` version supports HTTP/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the timestamps that seem to come from the HTTP/2 subsystem in Apache being incredibly broken, we're seeing that your HTTP/2 connection is a HTTP/1.1 connection being upgraded to HTTP/2. In that light, having two log entries is perfectly sensible.

From the [HTTP/2 FAQ](https://http2.github.io/faq/#can-i-implement-http2-without-implementing-http11):

> ## Can I implement HTTP/2 without implementing HTTP/1.1?
>
> Yes, mostly.
>
> For HTTP/2 over TLS (h2), if you do not implement the http1.1 ALPN identifier, then you will not need to support any HTTP/1.1 features.
>
> For HTTP/2 over TCP (h2c), you need to implement the initial upgrade request.

You're **not** doing TLS, so you're doing `h2c`. Hence, that HTTP/1.1 request is inevitable.

Comment: > "the timestamps that seem to come from the HTTP/2 subsystem in Apache being incredibly broken" Is this a known issue? Newer versions have already fixed that?

Comment: > "HTTP/2 connection is a HTTP/1.1 connection being upgraded to HTTP/2" Ok, the `curl` output is crystal clear about that. However, in the `access.log` seems to be backwards: 1st there is a HTTP/2.0 request than there is a 'downgrade' to HTTP/1.1. Mind to reconcile?

Comment: > "You're not doing TLS, so you're doing h2c. Hence, that HTTP/1.1 request is inevitable." Ok, I will self-sign a certificate and enable SSL in order to check that.

Comment: @JeronBaffom timestamps: less likely a problem with the software as is, more likely with how you set it up.

Comment: @JeronBaffom order in log seems backwards: yeah, due to totally broken timestamps, and hence, the logging system flushing messages to disk in the wrong order!

Comment: @JeronBaffom note that you *can* do HTTP/2 directly over TLS; but you don't *have* to. You need to correctly set up your server to do what you want.

Comment: > "more likely with how you set it up": As I described in the OP, just a fresh new standard Debian installation. I haven't changed any configuration file neither installed anything else other than Apache + SSH.

Comment: > "yeah, due to totally broken timestamps": Ok, but I've thought Apache wrote logs in the order of execution regardless of the timestamp.

Comment: If two processes send a log message from different threads, the logger has to decide which goes first. If you want non-blocking logging, there's no real way around atomically logging messages sorted by logging time with small time windows. I believe that is what happens here. The real question is where on earth these time stamps come from.

Comment: > "where on earth these time stamps come from.": Any chance this is actually an intentional design choice rather than me setting it up wrong?

Comment: I really couldn't see any intentional printing of a pre-1970 timestamp in a log. The situation pretty clearly is that invalid times get passed through some timezone-adjusting function and then through a printing function.

Comment: Since you say this is a 100% clean debian installation, it would probably worth your time reporting these timestamps as bugs to debian.

Comment: > "I really couldn't see any intentional printing of a pre-1970 timestamp in a log.": Not that I agree with such design choice, but maybe Apache is printing 0 as a way of saying 'ignore this line, focus at the other one'.

Comment: > "reporting these timestamps as bugs to debian.": Mind to explain how?

Answer (score 1):

You've hit a bug in the http2 module for Apache. I reported it 2023-11-22 and it was fixed the day after, see [Broken date in case of h2c w/ `curl --http2` · Issue #272 · icing/mod_h2](https://github.com/icing/mod_h2/issues/272)

According to the developer a `req->request_time = apr_time_now();` was missing in `mod_http2/h2_request.c`.

Comment: Anyone can report bugs to the Apache Team?

Comment: Anyone who knows the basics. But note that I reported the bug at Stefan Eissing's Github repo for mod_h2.